# I need a regex expression for validating sri lankan vehicle number

Tags: c#, regex, validation

My vehicle number is something like this.

```
1-0001,
10-0010,
111-000

A-3049,
KJ-6825,
AAC-3422
```

The following expression is the one I found.

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1,3}|([0-9]{1,3}))-[0-9]{4}
```

But I want that first three characters should not be all zeros or last four characters not be all zeros how do I make a valid expression ?

Comment: is this number correct :`111-000` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1,3}|((?!0*-)[0-9]{1,3}))-[0-9]{4}(?<!0{4})
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/12

The `lookahead` and `lookbehind` will make sure that there are no all `0\s` at start or all `0's` at end.

Also use

```
^(?>[a-zA-Z]{1,3}|(?!0*-)[0-9]{1,3})-[0-9]{4}(?<!0{4})
```

To make sure you dont make partial matches.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/13

Comment: Good pattern with few steps, you can improve it if you remove the useless group and if you make the first group atomic.

Comment: Yes they are, only possessive quantifiers are not supported. http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^((?!0000)([a-zA-Z]{1,3}|([0-9]{1,3}))-[0-9])|(([a-zA-Z]{1,3}|([0-9]{1,3}))-[0-9])(?!000)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fG1Kj5-Cco7WN003)

Answer (score 0):

And what about this:

^([0-9]{1,3}|[A-Z]{1,3})-[0-9]{1,4}